# Escaped single quote ignored in SELECT clause

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Not sure why the escaped single quote doesn't appear in the SQL output. Initially tried this in Jupyter notebook, but reproduced it in PySpark shell below.

```sh
$ pyspark
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Using Python version 3.6.3 (default, Oct 13 2017 12:02:49)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> spark.version
'2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292'

>>> spark.sql("select 'This is Bob''s home' as column1").show(truncate=False)
+-----------------+
|          column1|
+-----------------+
|This is Bobs home|
+-----------------+
```

Output shows `Bobs home` instead of `Bob's home`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use backslash instead of a single quote to escape a single quote:

```
spark.sql("select 'This is Bob\\'s home' as column1").show()
+------------------+
|           column1|
+------------------+
|This is Bob's home|
+------------------+
```

Alternatively, you can use double quotes to surround the string, so that you don't need to escape the single quote:

```
spark.sql("""select "This is Bob's home" as column1""").show()
+------------------+
|           column1|
+------------------+
|This is Bob's home|
+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess Spark 2.3 version isn't entirely ANSI complaint...